Why don't disturbances/wind move at the speed of sound in air?
Why don't sound waves move at the same speed as air that has a pressure differential? Imagine you have a box that is filled with air. One half high pressure air, the other half low pressure. They are not separated. When the high pressure air flows to the low pressure, the molecules collide and move at the speed of sound. Why doesn't this make the disturbance move at the speed of sound AKA, why doesn't the high pressure side travel to the low pressure side at 343 m/s?
(I acknowledge that in an ideal gas, molecules don't collide with other air molecules, but I think it is probably essential to consider that they actually do in this question. Not sure, but I would think so)
I’ve heard the argument that pressure waves move at the speed of sound, not disturbances. The thing is, what is a disturbance if it’s not a pressure wave? Wind/disturbances are pressure waves, if they weren’t then air wouldn’t move, I don’t think.
Basically, what differs to make a sound wave move at 343 m/s, but an air disturbance does not?

Air will move to fill a vacuum at the speed of sound: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/468211/how-fast-will-air-travel-to-fill-a-vacuum

Sound moves faster because it consists of energy that's skipping through the air molecules. The air molecules themselves don't move except a short little bit of vibration.
When the wind blows, mass as is actually shoved across space, not just energy.
Same thing here:

The energy moves through the balls at the speed of sound in metal -- much faster than the balls themselves swing.

faster, in subsonic flows ;)

Yeah, but I don't think the OP was talking about supersonic explosions. He was talking about the wind.

Consider two large pressure vessels connected by a pipe that has a valve. When we open the valve, the air flow velocity (wind speed) in the pipe is a function of the pressure difference between the two vessels. with a bit of engineering we can arrange for the pressure in the two vessels to remain constant, but there will still be a steady flow in the pipe connecting them, so the wind speed is independent of any change in pressure of the two vessels and only depends on the difference in  pressures. If the difference in pressures of the vessels is small, the wind speed can be much less than the speed of sound. If we define a disturbance as a sudden change in the pressure of one of the vessels, this sudden change of pressure is transmitted at the speed of sound in air. In fact if the air speed in the pipe is v and the speed of sound in air is c, the disturbance will be transmitted at a velocity of c+v.
